# Проверка структуры JSON объекта

Tags: javascript, json, структуры-данных

#### Описание

Сделал в сайте возможность импортировать .json файл.
Вот допустим пользователь импортировал какой-то JSON. Оно приходит, я делаю `JSON.parse()` и получаю какой-то объект. Теперь мне надо проверить, чтобы структура объекта точь-в-точь совпало с такой структурой.․․

```ts
{
    title: String,
    date: Number,
    poles: Array<{
        question: String,
        answer: Number,
        cases: Array<String>,
    }>,
}
```

...так же не был `null`, `undefined` или что-то ещё.

#### Мой вариант

Мое решение - пройти по объекту через `Reflect.get()` и проверить типы с помощью `typeof()` и `instanceof`. Пример:

```js
const object = // допустим объект получили
if (object && typeof(object) == `object`) {
    const title = Reflect.get(object, `title`);
    if (title && typeof(title) == `string`) {
        ...
    } else {
        throw new TypeError(`Invalid structure.`);
    }
} else {
    throw new TypeError(`Invalid structure.`);
}
```

Но мне этот метод кажется очень... "чайничным".

#### Вопрос

Может вы предложите методы получше?

Comment: Это же обычная валидация. Если схема может быть захардкожена, то ваш вариант нормальный. Для получения свойства не обязательно использовать рефлексию, можно просто обратиться к нему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы не предполагаете частое изменение схемы, то её можно захардкодить как набор проверок. Если схема должна быть динамической, то можно воспользоваться [json-schema](https://json-schema.org/) и готовым валидатором (https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=json-schema).

Reflect.get использовать не обязательно. `if (typeof(object.title) !== 'string')` тоже будет работать.